# Exception Logging Without using try catch - ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I need to log exceptions and bad requests in my API. Currently  I am using try catch to catch the exception and add to my logs in the catch block. Is this the right way? I read about Global Error Handling in ASP.NET. How can I implement that approach for this case?

Below is my API Controller example:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[ValidateModel]
[Route("CheckProgramOwner")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CheckProgramOwner([FromBody] CheckProgramOwner _data)
{
    try
    {              
        using (var db = new VisualVoiceFlowEntities())
        {
            var Result= await db.VVF_ScriptFlow.Where(s => s.ProgramId == _data.ProgramId).OrderByDescending(s => s.ID).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if(Result== null)
            {
                Log.Error("Error in CheckProgramOwner POST Request - " + "ProgramId not found");
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "ProgramId not found");
            }
            string CurrentOwner = Result.ReadBy.ToString();
            return Ok(CurrentOwner);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Log.Error("Error in CheckProgramOwner POST Request - " + ex.Message, ex);
        NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.NoticeError("Error in CheckProgramOwner POST Request - " + ex.Message, null);
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Internal Server Error. Please Contact Admin.");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to log exceptions it's pretty hard without catching them. The bad practice comes into play when you're using try/catches to drive the logic of your app.

Comment: ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core?

Comment: @GabrielLuci ASP.NET

Comment: maybe start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling

Comment: What @CaseyCrookston said. The example in that article shows you how to use an `ExceptionHandler` to catch exceptions and manipulate the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using ExceptionFilter. 
I created Exception Filter Class as below -

```
public class MyExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["addr"] = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
            log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["Hostname"] = Dns.GetHostName().ToString();
            log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["PCName"] = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Environment.MachineName)[0].ToString();
            string RequestMethod = context.Request.Method.Method;
            dynamic ControllerInfo = context.ActionContext.ControllerContext.Controller;
            string RequestName = ControllerInfo.Url.Request.RequestUri.LocalPath.ToString().Replace("/api/", "").Replace("/VVFAPI", "");
            Log.Error("Error in " + RequestName +" "+ RequestMethod+ " Request - " + context.Exception.Message, context.Exception);
            NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.NoticeError("Error in " + RequestName + " " + RequestMethod + " Request - " + context.Exception.Message, null);
            HttpResponseMessage msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
            {
                Content = new StringContent("Internal Server Error. Please Contact Admin."),
                ReasonPhrase = "Critical Exception."
            };
            context.Response = msg;
        }
    }
```

Also, I changed my controller accordingly

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        [ValidateModel]
        [MyExceptionFilter]
        [Route("CheckProgramOwner")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CheckProgramOwner([FromBody] CheckProgramOwner _data)
        {
            Log.Info("CheckProgramOwner POST Request");
            using (var db = new VisualVoiceFlowEntities())
            {
                var Result = await db.VVF_ScriptFlow.Where(s => s.ProgramId == _data.ProgramId).OrderByDescending(s => s.ID).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                if (Result == null)
                {
                    Log.Error("Error in CheckProgramOwner POST Request - " + "ProgramId not found");
                    return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "ProgramId not found");
                }
                string CurrentOwner = Result.ReadBy.ToString();
                return Ok(CurrentOwner);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the document previously posted by Casey, you will find a link to the following document, which explains how to implement and register an exception filter globally:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling#registering_exception_filters

You could then implement your logging logic in the filter's body thus avoiding having to repetitively log errors on each try/catch. I would suggest logging the more obvious errors using your original approach and use the filter to log any other errors (that you might not expect.)